# PHP adding array onto array

Tags: php, arrays, regex, loops

I'm trying to add onto an array while looping, although i'm not able to figure out how exactly to do this:

```
<?php

$original = array (
            array ("title" => "one",
                  "color" => "blue"
                  ),
            array ("title" => "two",
                   "color" => "green"
                  )
                );


$merged = array();

$str = "000three000red0!000four000white0!000five000black0!";
$pat = "/\d+(\D+)\d+(\D+)\d!/um";

preg_match($pat, $str, $match);

foreach($match as $result) {

    $merged = array_merge($original,array("title" => $match[1], "color" => $match[2]));

    print_r($merged);

}
```

The first problem is that is only seems to pick up the first match, the second being nothing ever gets added to $merged. I was hoping to have it output as:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => one
            [color] => blue
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => two
            [color] => green
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [title] => three
            [color] => red
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [title] => four
            [color] => white
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [title] => five
            [color] => black
        )

)
```

Comment: You need [`preg_match_all()`](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) not just `preg_match()`. `preg_match()` will stop after first occurance of your pattern.

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER, i didn't know that. is there a reason it stops after the first match?

Comment: Yes beacause it's `preg_match()`s behavior to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full, including the preg_match_all:

```
$original = array (
        array ("title" => "one",
              "color" => "blue"
              ),
        array ("title" => "two",
               "color" => "green"
              )
            );


$merged = array();

$str = "000three000red0!000four000white0!000five000black0!";
$pat = "/\d+(\D+)\d+(\D+)\d!/um";

preg_match_all($pat, $str, $match);

$merged = $original;
$i = 0;
foreach($match[1] as $result) {
    $merged[] = array("title" => $match[1][$i], "color" => $match[2][$i]);
    $i++;
}

print_r($merged);
```

results in:

```
    Array (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [title] => one
                [color] => blue
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [title] => two
                [color] => green
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [title] => three
                [color] => red
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [title] => four
                [color] => white
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [title] => five
                [color] => black
            )

    )
```

Comment: This seems to shove everything into groups by color, or title. I was needing to keep them in their own pairs. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is:

```
foreach($match as $result) {

    $merged = array_merge($original,array("title" => $match[1], "color" => $match[2]));

    print_r($merged);

}
```

In each step of your loop you merge original array with new array and save the output into merged array so in fact you don't change original array and each time you set merged value again.

Change it into:

```
$merged = array(); // or $merged = $original; depending on your exact needs

foreach($match as $result) {

    $merged = array_merge($merged,array("title" => $match[1], "color" => $match[2]));

    print_r($merged);

}
```

Comment: This seems to forget about the `$orginal` array, and also doesn't keep the items in their own pair. thanks.